# Rails Linking to action in controller from view with data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, parameters

i know there is a more elegant way to do this, but i can't figure it out, my brain must be stuck in the "S" gear.

```
<% @imageline.each do |album| %>
   <%link_s = '/prepdownload?tag=gorilla'%>
   <%=link_to (link_s) do %>
     <%= image_tag src ='gorilla.jpg' %>
   <%end%>
<%end%>
```

i have a controller action prepdownload that i need to pass the id of the image that get's clicked.  As soon as i try to force the action, the other methods break down on me.

{"tag"=>"gorilla", "controller"=>"profiles", "action"=>"prepdownload"} i can't reverse engineer the result in a more elegant way than above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a query string.

You could write out a manual URL hash like this:

```
<%= link_to {controller: "profiles", action: "prepdownload", tag: "gorilla"} do %>
  <%= image_tag src ='gorilla.jpg' %>
<% end %>
```

But the elegant way is to use a named route

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'prepdownload', to: 'profiles#prepdownload', as: :prepdownload
```

then call the named route, passing in your query string parameters:

```
<%= link_to prepdownload_path(tag: "gorilla") do %>
  <%= image_tag src ='gorilla.jpg' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: okay, that was too easy:).  Just to extend it a bit. I added to the query string by doing  (tag: "gorilla", name: "coco").  It all works nicely.  I did have the named path, but i guess I never tried to use it for some reason.

Comment: BTW, what got me hosed up was that your first method, which i tried errors with syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'   And i failed to mention that I am using Rails 4.0, if that makes a difference

Comment: @user2406315 Sorry, are you asking me a question?

Comment: My apologies.  I wondered if something changed in Rails 4.0. or I erred when i tried the manual hash, since i couldn't get it to work.